# ASP.net MVC - using AuthorizeAttribute in multiple environments with Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, windows-authentication

I'm using windows authentication in my ASP.net MVC 3 application. I have a few different roles in my system:

```
Administrator
PowerUser
GeneralUser
```

We have a rule in place that the AD group names are different in each environment.

For example, in Development the role names will be:

```
Administrator_Dev
PowerUser_Dev
GeneralUser_Dev
```

In production it would just be:

```
Administrator
PowerUser
GeneralUser
```

Is there a good solution for using Authorize in these different environments without changing the code when I need to deploy to a different environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just implement all of the roles?  Unless there's a chance of an Administrator_Dev role being the production site...

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator_Dev, Administrator")]
```

Comment: I could, but I don't really like seeing that in my code. More of a preference than a problem, I guess. Was just hoping there was a more elegant solution.

Comment: @Dismissile - I think it's actually very elegant.  At least More elegant than Aliostad's solution.  Your other option would be to add them as Web.Config entries and load them, which is even more ugly and more of a headache.

Comment: @Mystere Man - I don't think you can load them from a web.config. Arguments passed to attributes must be resolved at compile time. I find both solutions good (provided that you don't forget to put these strings in a constant variable)

Comment: @PenchoIlchev - You're right, brain fart.. I was thinking about loading them into variables that were referenced at compile time, but of course you can only use constants, so that won't work.

Comment: But hang on if access is given to both roles "Administrator_dev & Administrator" then Administrators_dev will get access to production which may not be right for many companies? Is there anyway?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I can think of is the conditional compilation.

Define these constants in a file with conditional compile.

```
#if DEV
public const string AdministratorGroupName = "Administrator_Dev";
#else
public const string AdministratorGroupName = "Administrator";
#endif
```

This is one of the problems with declarative authorization using custom attributes that needs to be defined at compile-time.

Another alternative is to have another custom attribute and implement the action filter yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I did by simply creating application specific configuration sections in **web.config**, putting the name of the environment specific AD group in the application configuration section and then use the configuration property on the Authorize Attribute. I can then change the group name by using custom web.config for each environment. For most applications, you need that anyway to be able to have different connection strings for each environment.  With this, you can just use the in-built Authorize Attribute.

Comment: This sounds like what I need, but I'm unfamiliar with web.config; an example of this would be helpful.